# wget with GET parameters?

Tags: linux, get, wget

I'm trying to use wget with GET parameters, but I think I'm missing something. Can someone help me to use it with these parameters?

```
GET /<api version>/<account>/<container>/<object> HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.swiftdrive.com
X-Auth-Token: eaaafd18-0fed-4b3a-81b4-663c99ec1cbb
```

I tried with:

```
wget -A "http://ipadress/get/v1/AUTH_test/test/test.jpg
         &Auth-Token:AUTH_tk7b471e3d3dff450d9b826c39eb3d29f1"
```

What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no GET parameters in there, just a path. `X-Auth-Token` is a custom header. Try:

```
wget -d --header="X-Auth-Token: eaaafd18-0fed-4b3a-81b4-663c99ec1cbb" http://ipadress/get/v1/AUTH_test/test/test.jpg
```

Comment: thank's i get : "403 Forbidden
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
URI content encoding = `UTF-8'
Skipping 73 bytes of body: [<html><h1>Forbidden</h1><p>Access was denied to this resource.</p></html>] done.
2013-07-16 03:11:22 ERROR 403: Forbidden."   I guess because another problem and not syntax now ??

Answer (score 0):

`X-Auth-Token` must be sent as a request header like so

```
wget --header='X-Auth-Token: eaaafd18-0fed-4b3a-81b4-663c99ec1cbb' -A ...
```

Comment: Thank's for the response, i think just option was missing have problem with!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Links` command line software for browsing html pages on terminal. For example:

`$ links http://google.com`